# Cloning wordpress to localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, clone

I'm trying to clone a wordpress website on to the local host to carryout a small development work and I'm having few issues here. Firstly, this is the procedure that I followed.

1. Installed XAMPP at C:\xampp on the Windows 10
2. Edited httpd.conf in Apache Config and changed to port 8080 by making the change `Listen 8080`
3. XAMPP runs successfully (both Apache and MySQL). When I visit the http://localhost:8080, I get the welcome screen
4. I go to `http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/` , I see the phyMyAdmin screen.
5. I create a new database with the name, `database` in phpMyAdmin and subsequently import the database file that I would like to clone. Before importing, I replace all the keywords that contain `localhost` to `localhost:8080` in the database file. The database gets imported successfully.
6. I copy all the wordpress files from the hosting server and place them in `C:\xampp\htdocs\wp`
7. Edit the `wp-config.php` and change the following:

   ```
   database_name_here to database
   username_here to root
   password_here to '' (blank)
   ```

When I go to `http://localhost/wp/` or http://localhost:8080/wp/, I get `HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.`

Can anyone point what is going on here?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed WordPress in your machine?

Comment: When you install word press it populates the database, If you copied it you do not have that data. Note also you want to match the directory with the server if you are copying files back and forth.

Comment: @Towerss No, I did not install locally as I copied the WordPress files form the hosting server. Would this pose a problem? @Wayne, I initially created a empty database with the name `wp` and later imported the `.sql` file to `wp`.

Comment: I guess you are not replacing website url like "http://example.com" with "http://localhost/example" . Consider sharing your db (.sql) file for better understanding of the urls replaced & to be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do more effort, just follow below steps after you copy all files, change config file & download SQL file from source.
1. > Open SQL file & replace "Live URL" with "http://localhost:8080/wp/" ( include HTTP:// & www)
2. > now import edited SQL on the local machine.
3. > open admin first from http://localhost:8080/wp/wp-admin
4. > go to settings > permalink section & click on save button.

That's it, your site now working on your local machine.

**Your 404 error may cause of "Step 4" to reset permalink.**
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/wordpress-features/reset-permalinks

Comment: Partially this worked. Thanks. I could not find any string with `Live URL` in the SQL file. What I did was replaced all the LocalHost:8080 with LocalHost:8080/wp. When I go to `http://localhost:8080/wp/wp-admin`, I get a login prompt. Not sure what would be the username and password here?

Comment: 1. > Your live url will be front url of your site for which you download sql file.

Comment: 2. > you username & password will be as it is from your site for which you are make cloning.

Comment: The steps you have described works. I changed all the live url's ti `localhost:8080/wp/` and I was able to login with the right credentials to save the permalink. Now, everything works.

Comment: Have Fun... :-)